# Gesture onSingleTapConfirmed strange behaviour

Tags: android

I believe in your bright mind and strong android skills. I am little bit stuck.

I have the following situation. I've created app for learning how to work with Gestures and canvas.

Idea is simple when I single time tap on the screen and where I've tapped should appear bubble (R.drawable.bubble). If there is already some bubble application should delete it (clear space).

But, I have some difficulties with this. Place where I've tapped and where bubble actually appears have some significantly different in position.

Please give some advice where  I should look. What I missed ?

Thanks in advance. Below I provide my code.

```
public class BubbleActivity extends Activity {

// Main view
RelativeLayout mFrame;

// Bubble image
private Bitmap mBitmap;

// gesture detector
GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bubble);

    // setup user interface
    mFrame = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    // load basic bubble Bitmap
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b128);
}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // init gesture detector
    setupGestureDetector();

}




private void setupGestureDetector() {

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, 
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {


            if(mFrame.getChildCount() == 0) {

                BubbleView bubble = new BubbleView(getApplicationContext(),
                           e.getX(),
                           e.getY());
                mFrame.addView(bubble);

            } else {

                for(int i=0; i < mFrame.getChildCount(); i++) {

                    BubbleView bubble = (BubbleView) mFrame.getChildAt(i);

                    if(bubble.intersect(e.getX(), e.getY())) {

                        mFrame.removeViewAt(i);

                    } else {

                        BubbleView newBubble = new BubbleView(getApplicationContext(),
                                   e.getX(),
                                   e.getY());

                        mFrame.addView(newBubble);
                    }

                }

            }




            return true;
        }



    });
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    this.mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    return false;
}


private class BubbleView extends View {
    private static final int BITMAP_SIZE = 64;
    private float mXPos;
    private float mYPos;

    private Bitmap mScaledBitmap;
    private int mScaledBitmapWidth;

    public BubbleView(Context context, float x, float y) {
        super(context);

        mXPos = x;
        mYPos = y;

        Random r = new Random();

        createScaledBitmap(r);
    }

    private void createScaledBitmap(Random r) {

        mScaledBitmapWidth = (r.nextInt(3) + 1) * BITMAP_SIZE;

        mScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap,
                                                  mScaledBitmapWidth,
                                                  mScaledBitmapWidth,
                                                  false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mScaledBitmap,
                          this.mXPos,
                          this.mYPos,
                          mPaint);
    }



    public boolean intersect(float x, float y) {

        if(Math.abs(this.mXPos - x) < mScaledBitmapWidth  
                || Math.abs(this.mYPos - y) < mScaledBitmapWidth) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bubble, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I have seen is that you should create the new BubbleView object outside your for loop.
I would use a boolean and if you don't find anyone inside the loop, then you could create one.

```
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        boolean found = false;

        if(mFrame.getChildCount() == 0) {

            BubbleView bubble = new BubbleView(getApplicationContext(),
                       e.getX(),
                       e.getY());
            mFrame.addView(bubble);

        } else {

            for(int i=0; i < mFrame.getChildCount(); i++) {

                BubbleView bubble = (BubbleView) mFrame.getChildAt(i);

                if(bubble.intersect(e.getX(), e.getY())) {

                    mFrame.removeViewAt(i);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                } 
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            BubbleView newBubble = new BubbleView(getApplicationContext(),
                               e.getX(),
                               e.getY());

            mFrame.addView(newBubble);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the code of a course in coursera!
I would recommend you using other options to find the solution (for example by reviewing the videos and the example code gived)

Comment: Yes this is from coursera but I didn't ask to give me answer for assignment. I just would like to some insight about particular theme

Answer (score 1):

Use following lines in BubbleView Constructor to set the position of your scaled bitmap.

```
            // Adjust position to center the bubble under user's finger
        mXPos = x - mScaledBitmapWidth / 2;
        mYPos = y - mScaledBitmapWidth / 2;
```

This will center the bubble view bitmap under user's finger. Coursera's skeleton project already includes these line.

Also, you need one more correction in your code -

```
     @Override

     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            return this.mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            //return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ignacio Rubio's suggestion to create the new bubble outside of the for loop however, in this particular scenario where the default value for found is false, the first click will create two bubbles: (1) to satisfy the condition of if(mFrame.getChildCount() == 0) and (2) if(!found)

To resolve this issue you can use an int in place of a boolean

```
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {

            int found = 0;

            if(mFrame.getChildCount() == 0) {

                Log.v(TAG, "Make First Bubble");
                BubbleView bubble = new BubbleView(getApplicationContext(),
                        event.getX(),
                        event.getY());

                mFrame.addView(bubble);

            } else {

                for(int i=0; i < mFrame.getChildCount(); i++) {

                    BubbleView bubble = (BubbleView) mFrame.getChildAt(i);

                    if(bubble.intersects(event.getX(), event.getY())) {

                        mFrame.removeViewAt(i);
                        found = 1;
                        break;

                    }else{
                        found = 2;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (found == 2) {

                BubbleView newBubble = new BubbleView(getApplicationContext(),
                        event.getX(),
                        event.getY());

                mFrame.addView(newBubble);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Also, double check you View.intersect(). The touch will have to intersect the x AND y position of the bubble rather than the x OR y position.